# Cannot connect atlas with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true }
);
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})



app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

.env file

```
ATLAS_URI=mongodb+srv://nitin:password@data.ztmkm.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

I am getting this error

> (node:16036) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: queryTxt
> ETIMEOUT data.ztmkm.mongodb.net
> at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:203:19) (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
> (node:16036) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
> rejection. This error originated either by  throwing inside of an
> async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which
> was not handled  with .catch(). To terminate the node process on
> unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag
> `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 1)     (node:16036) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning:
> Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise
> rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process
> with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: `queryTxt ETIMEOUT` is DNS error.  Make sure your DNS server can lookup SRV and TXT records

Answer (score 1):

mongoose.connect() method will throw a promise after successfully connecting to your db and you didn't write a code to recive the promise
so instead of this

```
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true }
);
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})
```

use this

```
const connect=mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true });
connect.then((db)=>
{
  console.log("connected correctly to the server")
},(err)=>
{
  console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: I tried to adding this previously but it still haven't worked.So to verify this I connected mongodb compass with the link provided in atlas for compass but still it gets timeout message